# Firebase Presence in Background Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get a list of users connected to internet and set their status as online. I am using Firebase Presence for it but it only works when the user in the application. When the user closes or minimizes the app, the status is set to offline but I want to keep the status online as long as the user has an active internet connection.

Note: I am using Android 8.0 and I know about limited background services.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Android may kill an app's process when it's no longer being used.  This is something you should expect to happen.  When that happens, Firebase will obviously lose its connection, and the app will be considered offline.

The only way to extend the life of your process is to start a foreground service in your app that stays active indefinitely.  Even then, Android may still kill your app to make room for apps that are visible on screen.  There is no way to guarantee that your app's process will never get killed for something more important to the end user.

[Please read this documentation thoroughly](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle.html) to understand how Android prioritizes apps.  Also read the documentation for [Service.startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also know about Service.startForeground() but the problem with it is that there should be a notification with it and I do not believe it is relevant to show the user a notification about a service that is keeping his status as Online ...

Comment: It doesn't matter what's relevant or not.  It's the rule you have to observe for Android development.