# Building online presence for an Android app with Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I need to implement online presence for my app which keeps track of when a user is online and when they go offline. I'm currently developing for Android using Flutter 3.0 and the Firebase database.

I have followed a solution from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) by using a Realtime Database to keep track of online users and a cloud function to update Cloud Firestore's online status.

However my Android phone seems to lose connection to the Realtime Database after some time.

Initially it was a few minutes, so I added permission_handler to remove battery optimization for the app so that it can run in the background and flutter_background.

However, for some reason it still eventually gets disconnected from the realtime database which then triggers the cloud function to set the user to offline. Judging from other answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286961/firebase-presence-in-background-android), there isn't a reliable solution for this method of online presence I am trying. Is there something I'm missing or a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

So what I tried that worked is to use flutter_foreground_task is running on Android and disable battery optimization. App stays awake for hours.

It is not an elegant solution. I guess a better solution for Android would be to create your own service that keeps track of the application being open.

This method would not work for iOS though.